# How to Query new sites in SharePoint tenant by querying on site creation date with Microsoft Graph API/SDK in C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

We want to query a SharePoint tenant periodically for any new sites/subsites created since the last time the query was run (e.g. once every 5 minutes).

We are open to running graph queries at the SharePoint tenant level or the SharePoint site collection level.

This tenant has >50,000 sites + subsites in it.  Enumerating them all takes too long. So we are hoping to create a graph query that can identify only sites with a creation date within a narrow range so we can make this process faster.

Cany anyone share more information on how to achieve such a query across the tenant, or site collection, for site creation date?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you go in the tenant's SP Central Admin site, you can view all sites in the tenant.  Actually, the data displayed in the page are based on listitems in a hidden system list. To list all lists, the query would be : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<yourtenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/Lists/?select=id,name`. So via graph you can query the listitems in the list with the displayname "`DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_ALL_SITES_AGGREGATED_SITECOLLECTIONS`". However I don't know if it is faster than the search query: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search='<site_name_or_alias>'`.

Comment: @RivoR. Oh interesting.  What about querying on creation date via a graph filter query.  Is that possible?  Because this way at least the result set is 5 instead of 40,000 (was my thinking)

Comment: @A X : Yes it is possible. Via the search query you can filter by the property `createdDateTime` as it is supported. Try : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search='<site_name_or_alias>'&filter=createdDateTime ge '2020-10-26T00:00:00Z'`. Via the list query, it is a basic filtering operation, so you can filter by that property too, I guess. The format of the date must be 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ'.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  Do you want to propose this as the answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: @A X : I rewrote my answer down there in the history so that you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to list all tenant's sites (large amount) is querying a hidden system list. It requires to have the right permissions to read listitems.

First, list all SP lists via the query: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<yourtenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/Lists/?select=id,name`

Next, via MS graph, you can query and filter the listitems in the list with the displayname `DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_ALL_SITES_AGGREGATED_SITECOLLECTIONS` as all sites' references are there. You can use the integrated pagination URL in `@odata.nextLink` property. Read : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging

Also, another option, via a search query it is possible too :
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search='<site_name_or_alias>'&filter=createdDateTime ge '2020-10-26T00:00:00Z'`.
However, beware of the fact that just a few properties are supported for filtering if you use the search.